# Installed application is not working giving error "The Application can not be started. Contact the vendor"

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, publish

i have published my application. it is installed but when i open it. it gives me error "Application can not be started. Contact the application vendor". when i clicked on error details it gives me this message:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34014
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34243 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34243 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/Faridullah/Desktop/RoshanQadri.appref-ms%7C

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\Faridullah\Desktop\RoshanQadri.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Value does not fall within the expected range.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [11/3/2015 4:03:21 PM] : Activation of C:\Users\Faridullah\Desktop\RoshanQadri.appref-ms| has started.
    * [11/3/2015 4:03:21 PM] : Performing necessary update check as specified by the deployment.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [11/3/2015 4:03:21 PM] System.ArgumentException
        - Value does not fall within the expected range.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String shortcutFile, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518112/how-to-find-out-what-causes-the-generic-application-cannot-be-started-contact and http://kb.calyxsupport.com/kb/article.php?id=702

Comment: It looks like you published your application to your desktop? This is not how ClickOnce works!