# Application can not be started. contact the application vendor

Tags: c#, windows

Installed application is not working and throwing an error

> The Application can not be started. Contact the vendor

I created a new project in C# and SQL Server; I use .Net Framework 4.6.1 on my PC and in Vb.net.

I create publish for application but when I want to install on another PC, I get this error:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 10.0.17134.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
clr.dll             : 4.7.3132.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST
dfdll.dll           : 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
dfshim.dll          : 10.0.17134.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
```

SOURCES

```
Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/alyossr.gf/Desktop/FinalTheShoper/TheShoper/TheShoper/bin/Debug/TheShoper.application
Application url         : file:///C:/Users/alyossr.gf/Desktop/FinalTheShoper/TheShoper/TheShoper/bin/Debug/TheShoper.exe.manifest
```

IDENTITIES

```
Deployment Identity     : TheShoper.application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil
```

APPLICATION SUMMARY

- Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY

Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.

> - Activation of C:\Users\alyossr.gf\Desktop\FinalTheShoper\TheShoper\TheShoper\bin\Debug\TheShoper.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
> - Specified cast is not valid.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY

```
No transaction error was detected.
```

WARNINGS

- The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
- The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS

- [8/17/2018 11:09:26 PM] : Activation of C:\Users\alyossr.gf\Desktop\FinalTheShoper\TheShoper\TheShoper\bin\Debug\TheShoper.application has started.
- [8/17/2018 11:09:26 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
- [8/17/2018 11:09:26 PM] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS

Following errors were detected during this operation.

- [8/17/2018 11:09:26 PM] System.InvalidCastException
      - Specified cast is not valid.
      - Source: System.Deployment
      - Stack trace:
          at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.VerifyRequestedPrivilegesSupport(String requestedExecutionLevel)
          at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
          at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
          at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
          at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
          at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
          at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
          at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

Comment: I found this forum thread after a verbatim search in Google for that error: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/57f09a43-8354-42fe-9e74-af6eb157a5b5/application-cannot-be-started-contact-the-application-vendor?forum=winformssetup

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "2.0" folder and try to install your application again.

C:\Users\ [your-username] \AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: My Friend this Sol. do not work for me @ehsan-mohammadi

Comment: @AyoubDesigner01 Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20595651/10223668) link. Hope this is what you need.

Comment: @AyoubDesigner01 Sure. Is your application console or windows form?

Comment: @AyoubDesigner01 See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229001.aspx) link. Refer to this link, "These are generic error messages that occur when the application cannot be started, and no other specific reason can be found. Frequently this means that the application is somehow corrupted, or that the ClickOnce store is corrupted."

Comment: my application is windows form