# How can I fix the 'Cannot start application. Contact the application vendor' error after a Windows 10 crash?

Tags: windows, vb.net

I am using VB 2022 and after a crash of my Win 10 system, I can no longer publish any program. I get Cannot start application. Contact the application vendor. That would be me. I tried the Start - run - CMD - rundll32 ofshim cleanonlineappcache  to no avail. I went to another program and did a clean/build/publish and it now acts the same way. Everything was working OK until the crash. I then did a install/repair of VS 2022. That didn't help either. I am >80 years old and the mind doesn't work so well. I keep programming because I love it and I think it keeps the mind working. Can anyone help?

Additional info:

I just uninstalled VS 2022 and re-installed it. . Here is a part of the log where I think the trouble is, but don't understand it.

> ERROR SUMMARY * Activation of K:\QDrive\Visual Studio 2022\Projects 76\Test For Publishing\Test For Publishing\publish\Test For Publishing.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected: + Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly Test For Publishing.exe. COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY No transaction error was detected.

Well, I don't understand what the above log means, so now I'm stuck with a great programming system and can't publish! How exasperating. I've done what everyone suggested. Any more suggestions?

Comment: This sounds more like a Windows than a VS/VB.NET problem. After the crash, have you done the typical stuff like running `sfc /scannow` followed by `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: I'd first try building a simple Hello World project from scratch to see if that works. If it does, then I would rebuild the other project by creating a new project and copying the files from your broken project one by one. Also, see this answer regrading the configuration file being corrupted: [user.config file gets corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518112/how-to-find-out-what-causes-the-generic-application-cannot-be-started-contact)

Comment: I did the above items; sfc /scannow and dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth and then re-compiled and published Hello Windows and it does the same thing...

Comment: I was able to delete 2.0 as suggested using cmd as admin. Rebooted and no difference. I deleted my Hello Windows program and rebuilt it again, still the same.

Comment: I just uninstalled VS 2022 and re-installed it. . Here is a part of the log where I think the trouble is, but don't understand it. ERROR SUMMARY

 * Activation of K:\QDrive\Visual Studio 2022\Projects 76\Test For Publishing\Test For Publishing\publish\Test For Publishing.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
  + Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly Test For Publishing.exe. 
COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
 No transaction error was detected.                                 Hope this helps.

Comment: @Larry: Instead of adding new information in comments, edit your question and add it there instead. You can find the edit link in the lower left corner, just below the tags. I've added your new info to the question for you.